# MapBox custom pin not showing

Tags: maps, mapbox

I have a custom pin but it is showing as an ugly default grey pin. Here is my function where I am setting my pin. This is inside of a loop that gets my pins

```
    featureCollection.features.push({
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": item.id,
                "title": item.title,
                "image":item.image,
                "description": item.description,
                "icon": {
                    "iconUrl": "../images/pin.png",
                    "iconSize": [29, 36],
                    "iconAnchor": [25, 25],
                    "popupAnchor": [0, -15],
                    "className": "pin"
                }
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    item.long,
                    item.lat
                ]
            }
        });
```

The example icon code was used from here https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to prep the custom marker

```
var customIcon = L.icon({
    "iconUrl": "../images/pin.png",
    "iconSize": [29, 36],
    "iconAnchor": [25, 25],
    "popupAnchor": [0, -15],
    "className": "pin"
})
```

then setup an options structure to use this new icon like

```
geojsonOptions = {
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latLng) {
        return L.marker(latLng,{icon:myIcon})
    }
}
```

and then include those options like this when adding to the map. `L.geoJson(featureCollection,geojsonOptions).addTo(map)`

Comment: Ok this works great for getting the icon in. For some reason now though the icons don't launch the overlays and i can still see the old icons behind the new ones.

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle?Or some of of your overlay code?

Comment: I've just added the JS here. Relies on other things which I can't push into JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/shanejones/tq02q5or/

Comment: Question - why are you not using `onEachFeature` of L.geoJSON for binding your popups to your features? I'm think watching `layeradd` is unnecessary and adds complication. http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature

Comment: I'm quite new to mapbox so have been using a mix of the mapbox examples and help from here.

Comment: Okay - do you actually need some of mapbox's features here or can we just go with vanilla Leaflet for simplicity's sake?